# Why does my for loop (i) stop AROUND 50,000?

Tags: loops, for-loop

Just a novice learner,having fun, trying to calculate some lotto fever odds.  The code I've written below simulates how many tickets I would have to buy before I struck all 6 winning numbers.  However, the code seems to exit the for loop and return an "i" of only around 50,000 loops, (instead of completing to the desired "i").  Please advise :)

```
function gen_num(range) {
  return Math.ceil( range*Math.random()  )
}

function gen_nums() {
  var arr = []
  
  for (var k=0 ; k<5 ; k++) {
    arr.push(gen_num(69))
  }
  
  arr.push(gen_num(26))
  
  return arr
}

function check_num(a,b,c,d,e,f) {
  var nums = [a,b,c,d,e]
  var counter = 0
  var counter2 = 0
  var ticket
  
  for (var i=0 ; i<10000000000 ; i++) {
    counter2 = counter2 + 1
    counter = 0
    ticket = gen_nums()
    
    for (var j=0 ; j<5 ; j++) {
      
      if ( nums.includes(ticket[j]) ) {
        counter = counter + 1
      }
      
    }  
       
    if ( ticket[5] === f ) {
        counter = counter + 1
    }
      
    if (counter === 6) {return "You win, it took " + counter2 + " tickets"}
      
  }
  
  return i
  
}
```

Comment: What are you running this code in?

Comment: What language is that?

Comment: Got back to a computer and ran this in my browser, looks like it's completing more than 50k loops for me.  I'm running this in a Chromium browser, I believe it'd be using the V8 engine.  Are you perhaps running this in an online REPL?

Comment: sorry, this is javascript.

Comment: sorry, this is in javascript

Comment: and I'm just running this on "jsbin" on chrome browser.

Comment: Yes, I think jsbin.com is an online REPL? is that where the limitation is, and not the code?